# How to invert fresnel effect

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am creating an island and adding a fresnel effect. However, the effect shows on the edges of my final render, but I want the brownish color to radiate out from the island. (See picture attached)[image: Island image]

Does anybody know how I can achieve this? (Note: The end result is the same with and without the invert node)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You want water to be more transparent showing more of the island?

Comment: I would take a different approach and use and Empty with a radial gradient (or you can do it with a gradient texture) to make that area more transparent. I would also probably avoid messing with the Fresnel. Set the IOR to 1.33 (because it's water). Another possibility is to use a volume shader to let the island slope show naturally, although could cost render time... many possibilities to play with.

Comment: Also either remove the *Invert* node from your node setup, or swap the *Transparent* and *Gloss* node sockets